# Magento prices including tax

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, tax

I have noticed that the tax wasn't working properly in my store, and set up a tax rule in my store. After I applied that rule to my products the tax is added to the price of the product, while I entered my prices including tax.

How can I apply the tax rate correctly?

EDIT

`Display Product Prices In Catalog` is set to yes
`System > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Settings > Origin` is also set to the correct country

Comment: try this:
http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/managing-taxes

Comment: Have you set product tax in `product edit > price tab > tax option`?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri I've there set it to the recently created tax group

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the setting in `Configuration > Sales > Tax > Calculation Settings > Catalog Prices` Set this to **Including Tax**